# Rename [wifi] to [wi-fi]

Tags: support, retag-request

"Wi-Fi" is the correct spelling. "Wifi" should be the synonym.

Citations:

- The Wi-Fi alliance makes extensive use of the "Wi-Fi" spelling on their [website (check the bottom for their trademarks)](https://www.wi-fi.org/), [page on Wi-Fi branding](https://www.wi-fi.org/who-we-are/our-brands) and their [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20110901225457/http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge_center_overview.php?type=2).
- IEEE papers on 802.11b uses the spelling "Wi-Fi".
- [Wikipedia's entry for wifi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wifi) redirects to Wi-Fi.

Comment: "WiFi" is a bit better than "wifi" as it asserts the etymology, compare history of usage of "hifi" from which it derives.

Answer (score 16):

I disagree with this only for the reason that words in tags are already separated by a `-`.

If the tag is written as [wi-fi](/questions/tagged/wi-fi) I will automatically read it as `Wi fi` (and probably pronounce it something stupid in my head like weefee :P) before I realize what it actually is.

Also the tag [android-wifi](/questions/tagged/android-wifi) would have to be changed to [android-wi-fi](/questions/tagged/android-wi-fi) which looks kind of confusing too.

Comment: You do have a good point on android-wi-fi. I agree with you there. Perhaps android-wifi is an acceptable compromise for simplicity sake?

Comment: As for misreading the tag wi-fi as something else, it should be the burden of the reader NOT to misread the word. ;)

Answer (score 6):

In a written text you would be right. But for a tag correct spelling isn't everything, it needs to be easy to read and to recognize. And I agree with Paul that a dash here creates an artificial separation which makes that tag harder to process. In the end, I think that the numbers speak for themselves: [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) currently has 664 questions whereas [wi-fi](/questions/tagged/wi-fi) only has 44. And that's despite [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) being slightly newer. So people clearly have a preference here and [wi-fi](/questions/tagged/wi-fi) should be made the synonym of [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi), not the other way round.

Comment: But can we actually tell if the people who used the tags "wifi" did so because of the number of questions tagged or because of their preference? Worst case is that people who used SO are misinformed on the correct spelling and are blindly following the numbers, regardless of their preferences.

Comment: Or they are unprepared for the grammar nazis out there and simply choose the tag name that appears logical ;)

Comment: That's a fair response. ;) I want to point out that there are grammar nazis whatever tag you choose, though. Moreso once SO establishes which tag should be used.